# How to share ACC model 3D viewer link with external

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-construction-cloud

I followed the steps highlighted in the article and was able to share a link with an external user to a Revit file that I have on Autodesk Construction Cloud.

https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-share-models-with-non-project-members-from-BIM-360-Docs.html

However, the link that it provides only lets users download the Revit file but doesn't show them a 3D view of the Revit file like we see on ACC. We would like to share this link with a large group of people and preferably not have to ask them to download the file and re-upload it to Autodesk's Viewer site. Is there any way to share a link to 3D view of the Revit file to external people through ACC/Docs?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid Autodesk Construction Cloud currently doesn't support this kind of feature. One option to work around this limitation would be to build your own "sharing service" that generates 2-legged tokens for public access to a specific design. We've implemented exactly that kind of sharing service [here](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-powerbi-tools/tree/develop/services/aps-shares-app) (in order to allow Power BI reports to access designs in ACC).

Comment: This 'sharing service', do you have any information about the legal status of this solution? It would be a very nice solution for us, but we can imagine that Autodesk does not want this to be used at scale, it will cost them licenses.

Comment: I'm not aware of any legal issues with this approach but will double-check with the appropriate contacts within the company. As far as I can tell, the only problem is a weakened security - if the sharing link gets in the "wrong hands", the design would be accessible by anyone and everyone.

Comment: did you already got some feedback from you're colleagues?

Comment: Not yet... I'll update this post once I do.

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother again. Any updates on this?